# How to find json direct parent based on children value

Tags: php, json

I need to find the direct parent of all instance of "type": "featured-product" in a JSON file using PHP. store this parent string in a variable. use a foreach.

In the example below, the variable would have the value "1561093167965" and "3465786822452"

I'm a little lost, thank you for the help!

```
{
    "current": {
        "sections": {
            "1561093167965": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            },
            "3465786822452": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            }
        }  
    }
}

foreach ($json['current']['sections'] as $sectionName => $section) {
    if ($section['type'] && $section['type'] == 'featured-product') {
      $featuredId = $sectionName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach you can take is to create a new array containing only `featured-products` using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then extract the keys. From the docs:

> If the callback function returns TRUE, the current value from array is
>   returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

```
$product_sections = array_keys(
    array_filter($json['current']['sections'], function($val) {
        return $val['type'] === 'featured-product';
}));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/e4CGb)

The problem in your original code is that your `$featuredId` variable is getting overwritten in each iteration of the loop, so when it ends its value will be the one of last element processed. If you have to deal with multiple values, you'll have to add it to an array or do the work directly inside the `foreach`. You can see the other answers for how to fix your code.

Comment: Looks great! But how would with this using a foreach and store each value in a variable (not an array). thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to get each value of the array your code returns in a foreach. How would I go to use each value of the array in a foreach? Something like:

foreach($product_sections as $single_value){
     $featuredId = $single_value;
}

Comment: @RaphaelBergeron Edited the answer to include why your code wasn't working. You have the exact same problem now, the `$featureId` variable is getting overwritten. Output the `$single_value` or call your functions inside the `foreach` .

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a cleaner way but this works using json_decode and iterating over the array with foreach

```
$json='{
    "current": {
        "sections": {
            "1561093167965": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            },
            "3465786822452": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            }
        }  
    }
}';
$e=json_decode($json,true);

foreach($e['current']['sections'] as $id=>$a){

if($a['type']=='featured-product'){
echo 'the parent id is '.$id;

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting an error of "Undefined variable: id" whan I try to use the variable :/

Answer (score 0):

```php
//change this with the real json
$json='{
    "current": {
        "sections": {
            "1561093167965": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            },
            "3465786822452": {
                "type": "featured-product"
            }
        }  
    }
}';

$result = [];
$jsond=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($jsond['current']['sections'] as $k=>$v){
   if($v['type']=='featured-product'){
$result[] = $k;

 }

}
```